# Where can I download ubuntu image with 5.11.0-27-generic kernel?

Tags: kernel

I want to download an ubuntu image so to make a bootable usb. Where can I download ubuntu image with 5.11.0-27-generic kernel?

Alternatively, is there any way I switch my current kernel to 5.11.0-27-generic through the command line?

Comment: 21.04 used the 5.11.x kernel, but the first time you run `sudo apt upgrade`, your system will promptly upgrade to 5.11.0-40-generic. Why specifically that older kernel? This seems like a possible [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic/download

If you are running Ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages, instead of doing so manually via this website.

You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` like this:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main
```

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections |grep linux-image` View the kernel image installed on the current system

then
`apt-get install linux-headers-XXX-generic linux-image-XXXX-generic`

Comment: What should I put for `XXX`  and `XXXX` in the commands?

Comment: View the boot sequence of the kernel in the current system: `grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: XXXX Modify to the corresponding kernel number

Comment: I want to install 5.11.0. My current kernel is 5.15.2. Why should I replace `XXX` with 5.15.2 when I want to install 5.11.0?

Comment: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-signed-hwe-5.11/linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic_5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1_amd64.deb

Download  and use dpkg command install it.

Comment: I just installed using the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

If your upgraded version is higher than the current kernel version, by default the newly installed kernel is started in the first order, just restart the system, otherwise, you need to modify the configuration file

```
vim /etc/default/grub
```

Modify GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux XXXX-generic", save and exit.

Note: For the old version of ubuntu (it seems to be before 16.04), GRUB_DEFAULT can be modified to the corresponding serial number. After 16.04, it should be modified to: Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux x.x.x-x-generic.

then

```
update-grub && reboot
```

Comment: I am scared of touching grub settings. I try reboot and pushing f12, f8, f10 to select booting 5.11.0 manually.